# How to integrate angular with .net blazor

Tags: angular, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side

I have already built set of modules and its working in angular. I don't want to rewrite them in Blazor. How to reuse them in Blazor?

I am able to render the angular component by selector on host.cshtml but only before blazor app tag. If i use selector anywhere else it renders and within seconds it's removed, the angular rendered html are replace by empty string.

Comment: choose one or the other...

Comment: Angular and Blazor both work by continuously 'rebuilding' the DOM. I can't imagine them living together in the same page, that just won't work.

Comment: I would switch to PHP if this is the case